# Bitmap images are not supported for PDF when setting output type is PCL - fop-pdf-images

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox, apache-fop, printer-control-language

I am trying to convert the PDF file into PCL output by using FOP. Able to convert png, pdf or tiff format other than PCL.

**XSL-FO** file for your reference

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
    <fo:layout-master-set>
        <fo:simple-page-master margin="1cm" page-width="21.0cm"
            page-height="29.7cm" master-name="A4-portrait">
            <fo:region-body/>
        </fo:simple-page-master>
    </fo:layout-master-set>
    <fo:page-sequence master-reference="A4-portrait">
        <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
            <fo:block>
                <fo:external-graphic src="url('hereforyou.pdf')"/>
            </fo:block>
        </fo:flow>
    </fo:page-sequence>
</fo:root>
```

**FOP configuration:**

```
   <renderer mime="application/vnd.hp-PCL">
      <rendering>quality</rendering>
      <text-rendering>bitmap</text-rendering>
    </renderer>
```

When i set the output mime type as MimeConstants.MIME_PCL, getting below error trace.

SEVERE: Error while rendering page 1. Reason: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while painting PDF page: hereforyou.pdf Bitmap images are not supported
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while painting PDF page: hereforyou.pdf Bitmap images are not supported
    at org.apache.fop.render.pdf.pdfbox.ImageConverterPDF2G2D$Graphics2DImagePainterPDF.paint(ImageConverterPDF2G2D.java:121)
    at org.apache.fop.render.pcl.PCLImageHandlerGraphics2D.handleImage(PCLImageHandlerGraphics2D.java:101)
    at org.apache.fop.render.intermediate.AbstractIFPainter.drawImage(AbstractIFPainter.java:249)
    at org.apache.fop.render.intermediate.AbstractIFPainter.drawImage(AbstractIFPainter.java:205)
    at org.apache.fop.render.intermediate.AbstractIFPainter.drawImageUsingImageHandler(AbstractIFPainter.java:170)
    at org.apache.fop.render.intermediate.AbstractIFPainter.drawImageUsingURI(AbstractIFPainter.java:292)
    at org.apache.fop.render.pcl.PCLPainter.drawImage(PCLPainter.java:159)
    at org.apache.fop.render.intermediate.IFRenderer.drawImage(IFRenderer.java:1294)
    at org.apache.fop.render.intermediate.IFRenderer.renderImage(IFRenderer.java:1281)
    at org.apache.fop.render.AbstractRenderer.renderInlineViewport(AbstractRenderer.java:858)
    at org.apache.fop.render.AbstractPathOrientedRenderer.renderInlineViewport(AbstractPathOrientedRenderer.java:832)
    at org.apache.fop.render.intermediate.IFRenderer.renderInlineViewport(IFRenderer.java:862)
    at org.apache.fop.render.AbstractRenderer.renderInlineArea(AbstractRenderer.java:715)
    at org.apache.fop.render.intermediate.IFRenderer.renderInlineArea(IFRenderer.java:926)
    at org.apache.fop.render.AbstractRenderer.renderLineArea(AbstractRenderer.java:690)
    at org.apache.fop.render.AbstractRenderer.renderBlocks(AbstractRenderer.java:572)
    at org.apache.fop.render.AbstractRenderer.renderBlock(AbstractRenderer.java:613)
    at org.apache.fop.render.intermediate.IFRenderer.renderBlock(IFRenderer.java:998)
    at org.apache.fop.render.AbstractRenderer.renderBlocks(AbstractRenderer.java:557)
    at org.apache.fop.render.AbstractRenderer.renderFlow(AbstractRenderer.java:458)
    at org.apache.fop.render.AbstractPathOrientedRenderer.renderFlow(AbstractPathOrientedRenderer.java:785)
    at org.apache.fop.render.AbstractRenderer.renderMainReference(AbstractRenderer.java:435)
    at org.apache.fop.render.AbstractRenderer.renderBodyRegion(AbstractRenderer.java:359)
    at org.apache.fop.render.AbstractRenderer.renderRegionViewport(AbstractRenderer.java:306)
    at org.apache.fop.render.intermediate.IFRenderer.renderRegionViewport(IFRenderer.java:737)
    at org.apache.fop.render.AbstractRenderer.renderPageAreas(AbstractRenderer.java:271)
    at org.apache.fop.render.AbstractRenderer.renderPage(AbstractRenderer.java:244)
    at org.apache.fop.render.intermediate.IFRenderer.renderPage(IFRenderer.java:587)
    at org.apache.fop.area.RenderPagesModel.renderPage(RenderPagesModel.java:193)
    at org.apache.fop.area.RenderPagesModel.checkPreparedPages(RenderPagesModel.java:174)
    at org.apache.fop.area.RenderPagesModel.addPage(RenderPagesModel.java:146)
    at org.apache.fop.layoutmgr.AbstractPageSequenceLayoutManager.finishPage(AbstractPageSequenceLayoutManager.java:316)
    at org.apache.fop.layoutmgr.PageSequenceLayoutManager.finishPage(PageSequenceLayoutManager.java:226)
    at org.apache.fop.layoutmgr.PageSequenceLayoutManager.activateLayout(PageSequenceLayoutManager.java:145)
    at org.apache.fop.area.AreaTreeHandler.endPageSequence(AreaTreeHandler.java:267)
    at org.apache.fop.fo.pagination.PageSequence.endOfNode(PageSequence.java:130)
    at org.apache.fop.fo.FOTreeBuilder$MainFOHandler.endElement(FOTreeBuilder.java:360)
    at org.apache.fop.fo.FOTreeBuilder.endElement(FOTreeBuilder.java:190)
    at org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerIdentityImpl.endElement(TransformerIdentityImpl.java:1102)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:609)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1782)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2973)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:117)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:848)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
    at org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerIdentityImpl.transform(TransformerIdentityImpl.java:485)
    at com.levent.fop.FOToOutputFormatUsingCustomURIResolver.generateDoc(FOToOutputFormatUsingCustomURIResolver.java:79)
    at com.levent.fop.FOToOutputFormatUsingCustomURIResolver.main(FOToOutputFormatUsingCustomURIResolver.java:43)

Please correct me if I missed anything.

Comment: `Bitmap images are not supported` is pretty descriptive I think

Comment: the issue is addressed in latest FOP jar